# SIgnal conversion (current -> voltage), robustness of methods

Tags: microcontroller, signal

I do want to read pressure sensors. The output is a 4-20 mA signal. I do have a couple of these [low current sensors](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8883) from Sparkfun at home.

On the other hand, I could go for a more robust solution (money is not the primary concern) and use some of these industrial [signal converters from ABB](http://new.abb.com/low-voltage/products/signal-converters/cc-e).

With the first option I could go for a small device, together with a small ADC. Everything inside a Box, probably with a Raspberry and touchscreen.

The second solution could be mounted on a "Hutschiene". Probably one of [these Controllinos](http://controllino.biz/) could serve as data aggregator. Data visualization, storage etc. could be done remotely e.g on a Raspberry or desktop PC.

Are the current sensing boards with the ACS712 suitable for this purpose ? Or do I run into some caveyeats ? For which solution would you opt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the current sensing boards with the ACS712 suitable for this
>   purpose ?

The ACS712 measures current up to 5A dc and has an accuracy of 1.5%:

> Total output error 1.5% at TA = 25°C

That means the accuracy in amps is 75 mA. This makes them totally unsuitable for measuring and reporting a 4/20 mA signal.

> For which solution would you opt ?

Clearly the ACS712 is unsuitable.

Try googling for circuits using op-amps like this 0/20 mA receiver: -

[image]

You might also want to consider a design that provides loop power: -

[image]

Comment: would have been nice to include the source of the image: http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5610